# mySql: reasonable limitations on bulk inserts

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

I am receiving a large amount of CSV data from a client that I plan to insert into a mySql database and process the data within my application. There are about 10 tables involved. The rows are less than 1k bytes each. What limits should I obey in individual insertions? I have quite a few millions of rows in each table to insert.

Let me know if there are salient data I should provide, such as the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `load data infile` to input the data into your tables, there is no limit that you need to obey.

Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have large number of insertions than you can use **INSERT DELAYED** query of MySQL or you can increase bulk_insert_buffer_size which is a system variable. Click [bulk_insert_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_bulk_insert_buffer_size).

For **INSERT DELAYED** syntax [Click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-delayed.html)